# Asymptotic distribution for moments of gaussian distribution

Tags: time-series, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem, moments, asymptotics

Is there a way to find the asymptotic distribution for the moments of Gaussian distribution?

More specifically, say you have $X_1, ..., X_n \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. For a moment $m_{n, k} =\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar{X}_n)^k$, we want to find an asymptotic distribution $G$, such that:
$$
a_n ( m_{n,k} - \mu_k ) \rightarrow G
$$
For some sequence of numbers $a_n$. Or maybe in a more general form: 
$$
a_n ( m_{n,k} - b_n ) \rightarrow G
$$
For some sequence of numbers $a_n$ and $b_n$.

PS. I am not sure how hard/easy the problem is. If it is easy, any hints/pointers are appreciated.

Comment: way to go with delta method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As given in [A. Dasgupta (2008) Asymptotic Theory of Statistics and Probability](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/probability/book/978-0-387-75970-8), ch 3, p. 42,

[image]

The reference to Serfling is 
[Serfling R.J. (1980) Approximation Theorems of Mathematical Statistics](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/book/10.1002/9780470316481).